# How to install debian on ubuntu 12.04 without uninstalling ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, debian

I am doing mcs and I am not able to install Debian on Ubuntu. Can anybody help me to do this? I want to do this without uninstalling Ubuntu.So please give me the answer in steps.

Comment: Can you define what mcs is?

Comment: I would assume Mono C# if it is about Linux @Mitch

Comment: @Rinzwind That would make more sense than my assumption of monte carlo simulation... lol

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your hard drive is set up my assumption is that Ubuntu is the only OS on your hard drive and you want to add debian as a separate OS that you can boot into.

What you need to do:

1. Shrink your Ubuntu partition using a tool such as gparted
2. Write a Debian ISO do a USB or CD
3. Boot into that USB/CD (much like you would have done for Ubuntu) and install on the newly made empty space (from step 1)